# Extremely stupid way to calculate expected value of a dice

Tags: probability, expected-value

Okay so hear me out.

Consider the random variable that is $Y_n = |X-n |$ where $X$ is the outcome of a fair $6$ sided die and $n \in \mathbb{R} $. Then by symmetry $\mathbb{E}[Y_1] = \mathbb{E}[Y_6]$. However $Y_6=|X-6| = 6-X$ and $Y_1=|X-1| = X-1$

Hence $\mathbb{E}[X-1] = \mathbb{E}[Y_1] = \mathbb{E}[Y_6] = \mathbb{E}[6-X]$ and so $2\mathbb{E}[X] = 7$ which then yields the standard result. I cannot help but think this " proof" is circular. Have I made a mistake somewhere and already assumed $\mathbb{E}[X] = 3.5?$

Comment: (1+6)/7 = 3.5 so what?  It that happens to be the same as E(X), it is just a coincidence.

Comment: (1+6)/7 != 3.5 @herbsteinberg

Comment: $BearCakes My mistake - I meant (1+6)/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, your proof is valid.  Here is a slightly streamlined version:-

Because of symmetry, $7-X$ has the same distribution as $X$.

$$7-X\sim X$$

Therefore they have the same expectation.

$$\mathsf E(7-X)=\mathsf E(X)$$

Expectation is a linear operation.

$$7-\mathsf E(X)=\mathsf E(X)$$

So this can be used to evaluate the expectation for $X$.

$$\mathsf E(X)=7/2$$

---

**Which does boil down to:** The distribution of $X$ is symmetric around the value 3.5 , therefore that is the expected value for the random variable.

Your proof shows why this is so, by the properties of expectation.

Comment: aye this was very nice. thank you also for the nice intuition at the bottom. Does this mean that $N-X \sim X \implies \mathbb{E}[X] = \frac{N}{2} $

Comment: Yes, indeed it does -- when $N$ is a constant.

Comment: Would it still work if N was a random variable and yield the result E(X) = 1/2 E(N) ?

Comment: Indeed, if you ever encounter such a situation, that will be the result.